# ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier::InvalidSignature in RegistrationsController#create

Tags: ruby, devise, rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm currently working on a Rails 6 application with `ActiveStorage` installed. I'm using devise for authentication. I the the following error when trying to create a new user on the sign up form.

`ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier::InvalidSignature in RegistrationsController#create`

I think the reason comes from trying to set a default avatar to the model `User`. When a user is created I'm trying to set `astronaut.svg` as the default avatar.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
  has_many :posts
  has_one_attached :avatar

  before_create :set_defaults

  def set_defaults
    self.avatar = 'assets/images/astronaut.svg' if self.new_record?
  end
end
```

How to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works for me:

```rb
def set_defaults
  if self.new_record?
    self.avatar = Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new(
      Rails.root.join('app/assets/images/astronaut.png'),
      'image/png',
    )

    # file = File.new(Rails.root.join('app/assets/images/astronaut.png'))
    # self.avatar = Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new(
    #   file.path,
    #   Mime::Type.lookup_by_extension(File.extname(file).strip.downcase[1..-1]).to_s,
    # )
  end
end
```

However I recommend not to send default image in `before_create`, but use a helper instead:

```rb
def user_avatar(user)
  if user.avatar.attached?
    image_tag user.avatar
  else
    image_tag 'astronaut.png'
  end
end
```

Comment: so use `:after_create user_avatar(user)`

Comment: You can use `user_avatar` in views.

Comment: Oh I see so not to use it in the model.